# Computing the radical of an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

What is the best way to compute $\sqrt{(X^2-YZ,X(1-Z))}$ ?

This is after using Nullstellensatz by the way as I thought it would be easier to compute a radical than finding the vanishing ideal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case there is no need to work over an algebraically closed field to get $$\sqrt{(X^2-YZ,X(1-Z))} = (X,Y) \cap (X,Z) \cap (Z-1,Y-X^2).$$

> The radical of an ideal is the intersection of the *minimal* primes over it.

Let $P$ be a minimal prime over $(X^2-YZ,X(1-Z))$. Since $X(1-Z)\in P$ there are two cases to consider:

1. If $X\in P$, then from $X^2-YZ\in P$ we get $Y\in P$ or $Z\in P$, so $P=(X,Y)$ or $P=(X,Z)$.
2. If $1-Z\in P$, since $X^2-YZ=X^2+Y(1-Z)-Y\in P$ it follows that $X^2-Y\in P$, so $P=(X^2-Y,1-Z)$. (Well, now we have to know that $(X^2-Y,1-Z)$ is a prime ideal, but this is easy: $K[X,Y,Z]/(X^2-Y,1-Z)\simeq K[X,Y]/(Y-X^2)\simeq K[X]$.)

**Edit.** If the field is algebraically closed I think is easier to find the radical of an ideal (as an intersection of primes) by using the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: I don't understand your edit. Could you please explain? How can the nullstellensatz be used to find the radical if the field is closed? By the way +1 :)

Comment: The nullstellensatz says that when the field is algebraically closed, then the radical of $I$ is $I(V(I))$. But as far as i know the nullstellensatz does not say how to compute the radical. That's according to my understanding.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Could you please point me to an example which illustrates that computing $I(V(I))$ is simpler than computing the intersection of minimal primes?

Comment: @Manos If I understand well you are actually asking about the finding of the generators of the radical, while I'm talking about writing the radical as an intersection of primes. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I am sorry, i still don't understand the edit. I just don't see why computing $I(V(I))$ is a simpler problem than finding the minimal primes of $I$.

Comment: How do you know that these equations are elementary and what does that mean? Also what are these equations? That's why i asked if you had an example which demonstrates that :)

Comment: @Manos You have an example on this page. But as I said, I'll look for more illustrative ones in the near future.

Answer (score 5):

You can just compute $\mathcal I [\mathcal Z [ (X^2-YZ,X(1-Z))]]$ ; assuming you're working over an algebraically closed field, notice that 
$$
x^2 - yz = 0 = x(1-z) \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad x=y=0 \quad \text{ or } \quad x=z=0 \quad \text{ or } \quad y-x^2=0=z-1,
$$
so that 
$$
\mathcal Z[(X^2-YZ,X(1-Z))] = \mathcal Z[ (x,y) ] \cup \mathcal Z[ (x,z) ] \cup \mathcal Z[ (z-1,y-x^2)].
$$
Taking the ideal of zeros of this union gives you 
$$
\sqrt{(X^2-YZ,X(1-Z))} = (X,Y) \cap (X,Z) \cap (Z-1,Y-X^2)
$$
(I used the fact that all three of these ideals are prime, so that they are equal to their radicals ; to see it, compute the quotient ring and see that they are integral domains.)

If your question involves finding generators for this intersection, I'll think about a hint later if you ask for it.

Hope that helps,

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791789/computing-irreducible-components-of-algebraic-set/791954#791954 for generators of this intersection.